# How do you convert a PHP Loop into JSON Loop?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, fullcalendar

this code will be used for Full Calendar JS :)

This is my PHP Loop, I got the data with my 'events' table on mysql db.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events";
$listEvents = mysqli_query($DB, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($listEvents))
{
    $id    = $row['event_id']    ;
    $title = $row['event_name']  ;
    $start = $row['event_start'] ;
    $end   = $row['event_end']   ;
    $url   = $row['event_root']  ;
}
```

And this is my code in Full Calendar, its the original from Full Calendar

```
events: [{
           id: '<?php echo "$id"    ; ?>',
        title: '<?php echo "$title" ; ?>',
        start: '<?php echo "$start" ; ?>',
          end: '<?php echo "$end"   ; ?>',
          url: '<?php echo "$url"   ; ?>',
        }],
```

Though the JSON displays my PHP Loop, but it only displays one row from my DB.

Thanks Everyone, I appreciate all your responses.

Comment: George Lemery  check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array outside of loop, and then assign all values to that array and then finally encode that array.

Do like below:-

```
$events = [];//create an array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listEvents)){//use assoc for lighter array iteration

    $events[] = ['id'=> $row['event_id'],'title'=> $row['event_name'],'start'=> $row['event_start'], 'end'=> $row['event_end'], 'url'=> $row['event_root'] ] ; //assign all values to array
}
```

***JS:-***

```
events: <?php echo json_encode($events);?>,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add all your data with appropriate keys in array then encode this data to json

**PHP**

```
$events = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($listEvents))
{

    $event['id']    = $row['event_id']    ;
    $event['title'] = $row['event_name']  ;
    $event['start'] = $row['event_start'] ;
    $event['end']   = $row['event_end']   ;
    $event['url']   = $row['event_root']  ;
    $events[]=$event;
}
```

**JS**

```
events: <?php echo json_encode($events);?>,
```